# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined - React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I'm encountering an issue while testing a React component using React Testing Library. The component involves fetching data using Axios. The tests fail with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.

      11 |
      12 |         const fetchFollowers = async () => {
    > 13 |             const { data } = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5")
         |                     ^
      14 |             setFollowers(data.results)
      15 |         }
      16 |

      at fetchFollowers (src/components/FollowersList/FollowersList.js:13:21)
```

Before I show the Test Suites, I just followed the tutorial of this git repository u can easily clone.

https://github.com/harblaith7/React-Testing-Library-Net-Ninja

So my Test Suite looks like this:

FollowerList.test.js:

```js
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import FollowersList from "../FollowersList";

const MockFollowersList = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <FollowersList />
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

describe("FollowersList", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        // console.log("RUNS BEFORE EACH TEST")
        jest.mock("../../../__mocks__/axios")
    })

    // beforeAll(() => {
    //     console.log("RUNS ONCE BEFORE ALL TESTS")
    // })

    // afterEach(() => {
    //     console.log("RUNS AFTER EACH TEST")
    // })

    // afterAll(() => {
    //     console.log("RUNS ONCE AFTER ALL TESTS")
    // })

    it('should fetch and render input element', async () => {
        render(
            <MockFollowersList />
        );
        const followerDivElement = await screen.findByTestId(`follower-item-0`)
        expect(followerDivElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
    
    it('should fetch and render input element2', async () => {
        render(
            <MockFollowersList />
        );
    
        const followerDivElement = await screen.findByTestId(`follower-item-0`)
        expect(followerDivElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
})
```

axios.js in **mocks**:

```js
const mockResponse = {
    data: {
        results: [
            {
                name: {
                    first: "Laith",
                    last: "Harb"
                },
                picture: {
                    large: "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/59.jpg"
                },
                login: {
                    username: "ThePhonyGOAT"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


export default {
    get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockResponse)
}
```

I'm working behind a proxy, but I don't think this is the problem here. Would be grateful for advice!

Greetings

Comment: Could the testing code be using the real `axios` by mistake? Because I'm not seeing how the mocked one could possibly return `undefined`. (Caveat: I don't use Jest, but the docs make it fairly clear what `mockResolvedValue` does.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes! I think so too, because the error shows code from the normal axios request instead some error in the mock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mocked version of axios in `__mocks__/axios.js` is being read but the problem is that react-scripts is adding the jest configuration `resetMocks: true` when runing the tests.

This effectively [resets all your mock implementations](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#resetmocks-boolean), removing all your fake implementations prior to executing tests.

You can override this configuration in `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
}
```

**Another solution**, if you don't want to change this configuration, would be to mock the implementation in your test:

```
import axios from 'axios';
[...]

it('should fetch and render input element', async () => {
    axios.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(<your_mock_response>);

    render(
        <MockFollowersList />
    );
    const followerDivElement = await screen.findByTestId(`follower-item-0`)
    expect(followerDivElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Since this mock is executed after the reset performed by the jest configuration, it allows you to add the fake implementation.

Comment: Thank u! It solved my problem! Just because of interest, is this related to the jest version? I run the same app on a different PC and it worked fine. But the package.lock was the same, so if im not wrong the version of my modules was the same too...

Comment: Can not say for sure, but if react-scripts dependency version number in package.json is not fixed maybe you are working with a different version of the package in each PC. Looking at their [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG-4.x.md), it seems that the change to include `resetMocks: true` was first introduced in version 4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchFollowers = async () => {

    const response= await (await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/? 
    results=5")).data;

    setFollowers(response.results);
}
```

Comment: I think this is probably not the solution because it would still try to use the real axios instead of the mock.